# Using pointers with Arduino

Tags: serial, c, pointer, memory, printf

I am learning about pointers.

I was wondering how the memory address is defined in programming. I get different outputs depending on the format I choose for memory address. So I was wondering if it is correct to assume that the format of the memory address is defined by the programmer. I get different results for memory address when I use `Serial.print( (long) &ptr1, DEC);` and `Serial.print( (long) &ptr1, HEX);`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int counter = 0;
   void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
   int test1 = 10; 
   float test2 = 3.14159; 
   char test3[ ] = "This is a character array";
   int *ptr1;
   float *ptr2; 
 char *ptr3; 
  ptr1 = &test1; 
Serial.print("The integer value is stored at ");
Serial.print( (long) &ptr1, DEC);

 Serial.print("The integer value is stored at ");    
  Serial.print( (long) &ptr1, HEX);


  } 
 void loop() {

    }
```

My output is:

The integer value is stored in  2296

The integer value is stored in  8f8

Comment: You realise you're printing the address if ptr1 here, not the test value (I think...) The formatting shouldn't make any difference - can you add example values that you get (when you print both values in the same program, re-compiling could potentially move these locations.

Comment: @Sean I have edited my question. It gives me 2296 when I put decimal format and 8f8 when I put Hex format

Comment: "Why do programmers always mix up Christmas and Halloween? Because Dec 25 is Oct 31" in your case "DEC 2296 is HEX 8f8".

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the address of the pointer, not the contents of the pointer.

Say you have the memory map of:

```
100 20       test1 low byte
101 0        test1 high byte
102 100      ptr1 low byte
103 0        ptr1 high byte
```

`test` is located at address 100 and takes two bytes. `ptr1` is located at 102 and takes two bytes. `ptr1` contains the address of `test` (100) and `test1` contains the value `20`.

The different possible combinations of prints are:

```
Serial.println(test1);  => 20 (contents of test1)
Serial.println(&test1); => 100 (address of test1)
Serial.println(ptr1);   => 100 (contents of ptr1 = address of test1)
Serial.println(&ptr1);  => 102 (address of ptr1)
Serial.println(*ptr1);  => 20 (contents of address pointed to by ptr1).
```

(note: some of those will require a *cast* in order for the C++ to select the correct `println()` overload function.)

Comment: Serial.print would not work for &test, I had to put (long) before that. I get different results for Hex and Dec. I have edited my question.

Comment: I purposely omitted the casts that you would need to get the right println overloads so it didn't get too cluttered. That doesn't make any difference to *what* is happening though. You need to learn just what & and * mean.

Comment: so 2296 is the same as 8f8 with different format?

Comment: You're trying to play with pointers and you don't even know the difference between decimal and hexadecimal...?!?!

Comment: `so 2296 is the same as 8f8 with different format` - yes. Google `0x8f8 in decimal`. You can get calculators that will do that for you. Probably is one built into your PC.

Comment: When you Google that Google even hands you a calculator right there in your browser.